# How do I stop css smooth-scrolling from scrolling horizontally?

Tags: css, horizontal-scrolling, smooth-scrolling

I have a website that has a fixed navbar with links that lead to anchor points on the page with smooth scroll enabled. Then I also have a slide-in on-scroll effect that slides elements in from the left and right once they become visible at the bottom of the screen. Everything is working fine, but the problem is that if I click one of the links in the navbar, the smooth-scroll not only scrolls down to the element, but it also scrolls horizontally. How do I stop that horizontal scrolling? I want it to scroll down and wait for the section to slide in.

I am very limited in what I can change because the website is built with a website builder so I can only change the css and tracking code. Ideally I am looking for something like the overflow-x: hidden property for the scrolling.

Here is the website so that you can check the problem out for yourself: https://smartlink.media

Here is my css:

```
html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

#section-Onx5wt3Yil, #section-dO8qdRXHGU, #section-uAY8pSt-bU, #section-JQC9MJbsWQ, #section-BvLFhwYeRK {
    height: 100vh;
    scroll-margin-top: 100px;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

#section-Onx5wt3Yil {
    transform: translateX(0);
}
```

And this is the js to slide the elements in:

```
<script>
  const sections = document.querySelectorAll('.section')
  window.addEventListener('scroll', checkSections)
  
  function checkSections() {
    const triggerBottom = window.innerHeight / 5 * 4
    sections.forEach(sec => {
      const sectionTop = sec.getBoundingClientRect().top
      if(sectionTop < triggerBottom) {
        sec.style.transform = ('translateX(0)')
      } else {
        if(sec.classList.contains('slide-left')) {
           sec.style.transform = ('translateX(-100%)')
           } else {
          sec.style.transform = ('translateX(100%)')
        }
      }
    })
  }
</script>
```